# create object key and property of object dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I want to create a new object dynamically and insert into the inside of columns object

```
dynamicCreate = [
    {
        columns: {
            title: {
                title: "Title"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Create dynamically like

```
name: {
    title: "Name"
},
```

and insert next of

```
title: {
    title: "Title"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the dot notation

```js
var obj={};
obj.title={};
obj.title.title="name";
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a dynamic language. so you can assign any props dynamically to the object.

```js
var obj={
  name:'foo'
};
obj.extraInfo={
  bar:'baz'
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: No need to apologies buddy. Just be a little diligent about it. Have a good day